# Error 404, not finding scripts on my computer

Tags: javascript, php

I'm making a small website, here are my script references.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" ng-app="App">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

.....

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I set up a localhost server using php, and I have a php index page that references the head. This was all working fine until today, and now when I try to run my web page via localhost, I'm getting error code 404, file not found, for all of the files on my computer. It's running the angular (links) scripts just fine. But anything in my css/js folders are not being found, even though I know I have the paths set up correctly. Any suggestions? I am navigating to the correct folder via the terminal before setting up the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Some servers require you to start them up every time if (like me) you uncheck the "run on startup" box (although this is unlikely because some of your stuff is running).

Also, could one of the js files have an error and thus not allow the rest to load? Try commenting out a the js files one by one.